# Dynamic jQuery menu with sliding pictures

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I need to make a dynamic jQuery menu for showing products.

There will be one main picture with text and  hyperlink on it, taking 60% of the screen, and on the right of it I need three small pictures (one above the other, horizontally) with 20% width of screen (but all together taking same height as the main one).

I need help for the animation. The animation will be next:
the three pictures on the right are sliding up, and the top most disappears, and a new one is appended to the bottom (at the same time as the top most is disapearing). Now, the one that dissapeared becomes the main one.

I've made an easy solution with .slideUp function, but that doesn't actually made the div go up, instead it is just losing it's height until it becomes invisible. It is not the solution I wanted.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I've managed to get some solution with jQuery.sliedUp function, but still I didn't get the effect that the client was asking for.

Now with a little bit more search, I've found that the jQuery UI hide function extension can do the effect I am looking for.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/WMPRJ/

My problem now is if you click on the top div, while it is sliding up, the bottom div does not follow it up and take its place. I need to do that. Please provide me with a solution.

Comment: If you can create a sample demo in jsfiddle.net people will understand your requirement much better.

Answer (score 0):

Append the current main to the bottom of your thumbnails, slide up the top one and `remove()` it.  Take its `src` attribute and set it to the main image.

Here's some (sorry, not a self-contained example) code that should get you where you're going.  If you actually take the time to read it you'll see it does exactly what I described in the first two sentences.

```
$('.thumb').first().slideUp(function(){
  $('#main').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Hi. I don't think you've understood my problem. I need a solution for sliding the four thumbnails up, the top one goes out of screen and the bottom one showing on the screen.

I need a working example with HTML and CSS included. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if this a homework please append **homework** tag.

I can't provide you with full HTML and javascript, but an idea. You have two blocks. Float the right block;

```
Left Block - 60%.
Right Block - 20% (float:right)
```

Define height for Right & Left block and give `overflow:hidden` for Right Block. 
Now define a click function like this.

```
var nextAnimateImageId = 1;
$("#my_button").click(function{

jQuery("#my_image"+animateImageId).animate({height:'toggle'});
nextAnimateImageId  = nextAnimateImageId + 1;

});
```

My idea is, if you have 5 images, only 3 will be shown becaue of defined height and overflow:hidden property. When you animate the first image to height=0 (which is what toggle does), the 4th image will come up due to the space freed up, giving you a nice scroll up animation.

Comment: It is not a homework. I've edited the question and there is a link to jsfiddle now. Please take a look at it. Thanks.